# How to resolve warning /usr/bin/ld: warning: libtiff.so.4, needed by /home/user/libs/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, may conflict with libtiff.so.5?

Tags: c++, opencv, warnings, tiff, libtiff

Some C++ project use TIFF library and OpenCV library at the same time.

The following warning is produced:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libtiff.so.4, needed by /home/user/libs/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, may conflict with libtiff.so.5,
```

How can it be resolved?

If it matters I'm using Ubuntu and Eclipse.

`/sbin/ldconfig -p > libs.txt` show me

```
libtiffxx.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiffxx.so.0
libtiffxx.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiffxx.so
libtiff.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4
libtiff.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so

libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
libopencv_highgui.so.2.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
libopencv_highgui.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
```

But I don't know what it means, different versions of library?

Comment: can you try to change version of libtiff in project?

Comment: @Hermann how it can be done?

Comment: Does it your project or you just compile sources written by someone?

Comment: @Hermann It's my project.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try the following:

1. find a newer version of libopencv_highgui.so compiled with libtiff.so.5
2. recompile libopencv_highgui.so with libtiff.so.5
3. delete libtiff.so.4 and make a symlink to libtiff.so.5 if you get a linker error

Comment: I don't know how to specify libtiff.so with version in Makefile I just add libtiff library as `-ltiff`. Also see update.

Comment: @Denis Zaikin Recompilation of the OpenCV library is very complex task

Comment: @mrgloom look at this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891692/linking-to-wrong-library-version-in-a-c-application There are many ways how to do it.